# Number of functions having no fixed points

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I had got a question

> A function $f$ from the set $A$ to itself is said to have a fixed point if $f(i) = i$ for some $i$ in $A$. Suppose $A$ is the set $\{a, b, c, d\}$. Find the number of bijective functions from the set $A$ to itself having no fixed point.

My solution is $4^4- C(4,1)*3^4 + C(4,2)*2^4-C(4,3)*1^4= 24$. But the answer given is $9$.

Am am I being wrong in using total derangements?

Comment: It is the number of derangements, and there are $9$ of them.  Note that $24$ is the number of bijections.  You aren't using the correct formula for the number of derangements.

Comment: The “universe” here is the set of all bijections on A, so you need $4!$ instead of $4^4$, etc